# GridView DataKeyNames of nested collections or custom object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, custom-object

I'm using custom objects to bind to a GridView.

Suppose I have a collection of Car Companies (Audi, Ford, BMW, etc). Each Company object has properties like Id, Name, Country, etc.

Each Company also has a Collection of Cars. Each Car has properties like Id, Model, Year, etc.

I want to bind this info to a GridView.

So I'm retrieving a query of Companies and in first object of each Cars Collection, has data of one car (the object model is like this because in other scenarios I have to list all the cars of a Company).

There is no problem when I bind the Gridview to the Companies collection. I can list each company and each car info I want to show.

The problem arises when I want to set the DataKeyNames. I want to set it with the Id of each Car (not the Id of each company) for comparing cars.

I was trying something like this:

```
GridViewCompanies.DataSource = companies;
GridViewCompanies.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "Cars[0].Id" };
```

But it does not work, it says  it does not contain a property with the name.

Is there any way to set it?

I don't want to bind the Gridview to a Cars collection instead because if I do it that way, I would miss the info of each Company and I need to use company's properties too.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
var carCompanyList = new[]
                    {
                      new { Id = 1, Name = "Audi", Cars = new[] { new { Id = 10, Model = "Audi_Model_1" }, new { Id = 12, Model = "Audi_Model_2" } } }, 
                      new { Id = 2, Name = "Ford", Cars = new[] { new { Id = 20, Model = "Ford_Model_1" }, new { Id = 22, Model = "Ford_Model_2" } } }
                    };

var gridViewData = from carCompany in carCompanyList
                    select new
                            {
                              carCompany.Id,
                              carCompany.Name,
                              firstModelId = carCompany.Cars == null || carCompany.Cars.Count() == 0 ? 0 : carCompany.Cars.First().Id
                            };

CarModelGridView.DataSource = gridViewData;
CarModelGridView.DataKeyNames = new [] { "firstModelId" };
CarModelGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you. So you're basically copying everything into a new collection. I wanted to avoid that solution. Is there any other option? Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I think unfortunately not cos DataKeyNames is list of names not expressions (see MSDN). Probably you should change class CarCompanies notably add Id-property explicitly. GridView expects prepared data and we should cook it :)

Comment: Just to update, I solved this adding to the car class a Company and a private property for accessing the companyID and companyName. This way I can have the structure car.Company.ID and car.Company.Name and use in the datakeynames the properties car.CompanyID and car.CompanyName (both references to car.CompanyID and car.CompanyName respectively).